# How to remove header footer and left bar on ui component in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to just show the customer table on page and need to remove header footer and left bar as well.How i can achieve it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from XML. You have to put this inside **body** tag. You can put this inside **default.xml** or any other XML which you want.

**Remove left sidebar:-**

```
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true" />
```

**Remove Header:-**

```
<referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />
```

**Remove Footer:-**

```
<referenceBlock name="footer" remove="true" />
```